# Scanner doesn't see after space

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program that asks for the person's full name and then takes that input and reverses it (i.e John Doe - Doe, John). I started by trying to just get the input, but it is only getting the first name.

Here is my code:

```
public static void processName(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");
    String name = scanner.next();
    System.out.print(name);
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Change  to  `String name = scanner.nextLine();` instead of `String name = scanner.next();`

See more on documentation here - [next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) and [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for the really fast response, really helped.

Comment: I'm having this same issue but the String I'm using nextLine() for ends up being empty. This is what my code looks like: `System.out.print("License plate: ");
String license = sc.nextLine();`. Did the Scanner change after this answer was posted?

Comment: Hi Alex, please find my answer here, see if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64991271/5345105

Answer (score 16):

Try replacing your code

```
String name = scanner.nextLine();
```

instead

```
String name = scanner.next();
```

`next()` can read the input only till the `space`. It can't read two words separated by `space`. Also, `next()` places the cursor in the same line after reading the input.

`nextLine()` reads input including `space` between the words (that is, it reads till the end of line `\n`). Once the input is read, `nextLine()` positions the cursor in the next line.

Comment: next() can read the input only till the **whitespace**. It can't read two words separated by a **whitespace**. **whitespace** includes space, tab and linefeed

Answer (score 4):

From `Scanner` documentation:

> A `Scanner` breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

and

> `public String next()`
>
> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

This means by default the delimiter pattern is "whitespace". This splits your text at the space. Use `nextLine()` to get the whole line.

Answer (score 3):

```
 public static void processName(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");
        scanner.nextLine();
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print(name);
    }
```

Try the above code Scanner should be able to read space and move to the next reference of the String

Comment: can you explain my doubt please - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64991271/5345105

Answer (score 2):

`scanner.next();` takes only the next word. `scanner.nextLine();` should work. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

In case you do not want to use `.nextLine()` you can also configure `.next()` to use `\n` as the delimiter pattern using `.useDelimiter()` method like so:

```java
public static void processName(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");
    scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
    String name = scanner.next();
    System.out.print(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
String name = scanner.nextLine();
```