# Why can't my 2nd If then statement match?

Tags: java, if-statement

First of all I am new to this site, but anyways, here is my problem. In my if then statement, I type in "Gen" and it works, but if I type "Launch nuke" or "launch nuke" or "Who am I?" it just ends up saying "Unknown Command" which means it doesn't match any of the statements (or whatever it's called). I tried using == as well but they both don't work. Of course I type Gen first and the Launch nuke after. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String alpha;
        String bravo;
        String charlie;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);         
        System.out.print("Please confirm identity: ");
        alpha = input.next();

        if (alpha.equals("Gen")) {
            System.out.println("Hello General"); 
            System.out.println("Identity Confirmed");
            System.out.print("Please input command: "); 
            bravo = input.next();

            if (bravo.equals("Launch nuke")) {                          
                System.out.println("Launching Missiles"); 
            }   

            else if (bravo.equals("launch nuke")) {
                System.out.println("Launching Missiles");
            }

            else if (bravo.equals("Who am I?")) {
                System.out.print("You are the General");
            }   

            else
                System.out.print("Unknown Command");
        }

        else
            System.out.println("Access Denied");                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Put code in proper format and use `{}` for if-else always.

Comment: As an aside, to save you having multiple conditions to deal with case sensitivty try invoking the `toLowerCase()` method on your input `string`

Comment: @Scott `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` seems a little more reasonable in this situation if you ask me.

Comment: @Dragondraikk ahh yes, I forgot about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input.nextLine()` instead of `input.next()` should fix it. Use it for both, alpha and bravo. 
`input.next()` only takes the next token into account (like "launch"), while your commands have more than one.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `input.next()`. It will read only one complete word for eg: *"Launchnuke"*. The `next()` method will split it to `string[]` with space.

So try using `input.nextLine()`, it should work.

Answer (score -3):

Oh I don't have enough reputation..
anyway.
you should type Gen first
and Launch nuke or any thing to do that
because your Launch nuke if statement is inside Gen if statement

Comment: you are having this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509647/scanner-doesnt-see-after-space-java