# How to read the user inputs(including spaces) line by line with Scanner?

Tags: java

I need to read user inputs line by line (may be included spaces). I had already read [Scanner doesn't see after space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509647/scanner-doesnt-see-after-space-java) question. So I used with `scanner.nextLine()` but this method does not help my program. Below is my sample program ....

```
public class TestingScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many friends do you have ?");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    String[] names = new String[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your name of friend" + (i + 1));
        names[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("*****************************");
    System.out.println("Your friends are : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(names[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("*****************************");
    }
}
```

While runnig my program , after inserted no: of friend , my program produces two lines as below. How can I solve it ? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `int size = sc.nextInt();` use `sc.nextLine()` to consume the newline characters, otherwise, they will be consumed by `nextLine()` in your loop and that is not what you want.

---

### Solution

```
int size = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: @Cataclysm Corrected.

Comment: yes ... now `sc.nextLine()` fixes my problem. Thanks