# Difference between String loaded from Scanner and JOptionPane

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, whitespace, joptionpane

I am wondering what's the difference between String object loaded from Scanner.next() and JOprionPane.showInputDialog("text");

I had a problem in my small program, when I used Scanner:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 String s = sc.next();
 s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

and I wrote, let's say "Dami an" the result was "Dami"

but when I loaded String using JOptionPane:

```
    String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Text");
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

the result was (as I expected in the previous example) "Damian".

Why the results are different?

Thanks for help :)

Best regards :D

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509647/scanner-doesnt-see-after-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sc.next()` only returns a single token, so it only gets the `Dami` the first time you call it, not `Dami an`. You'd get `an` if you called `sc.next()` again.

Use `sc.nextLine()` if you want to get the whole line at once.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Scanner.next()` method fetches next token which is `Dami`, the `an` is the second token just after `Dami`.

If you want whole line to be read the most efficient(performance-wise) way you might want to use:

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
String s = br.readLine();
}catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Or Scanner#nextLine depending on your needs

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is `Scanner.nextLine()` faster in any situation? I read that it has buffer under it but when I used scanner to read numbers into arrray and measured time it was always slower than `BufferedReader.nextLine()` and then `String.split()` and then `Integer.parseInt()` which seams weird.

Comment: This isn't a time critical question, the simplest solution to solve the op's problem is to use nextLine. Would I use Scanner? Probably not, but it wasn't available when I started with Java (ps I'm not complaining about your answer per say, just that in this case, next/nextLine are the differences)