# ending a while loop condition

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a simple program that uses a scanner for input and has a while loop that continues taking input until an end character is entered. I want the scanner to take input and add a string to the stack list. I'm trying to figure out why this code doesn't terminate the while loop when a space is typed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseString<E> {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack();

    //while(scan.hasNext() && !stack.equals(" ")){
 //       while(!scan.nextLine().equals("")){
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        stack.push(scan.next());
        if (scan.equals(" ")) {
            break;
        }

    }

    System.out.print(stack.pop() + " ");


 }
}
```

Comment: do you press the `ENTER` key?

Comment: It's not ending upon hitting enter.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509647/scanner-doesnt-see-after-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `nextLine` instead

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String nextInput = scan.nextLine();
    stack.push(nextInput );
    if (nextInput.equals(" ")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. I tried the others and they didn't work.

Comment: I did upvote. I'm not sure why but someone had previously downvoted it for some reason. Accepted as correct answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    stack.push(scan.next());
    if (scan.equals(" ")) {
        break;
    }

}
```

change to

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String value = scan.nextLine();
    if (" ".equals(value)) {
        break;
    }
    stack.push(value);
}
```

scan is a Scanner, it's not a String, `scan.equals(" ")` would always return false.

Comment: Good spotting with `scan.equals` but did you test it?

Comment: Thanks for point out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class

Answer (score -1):

You're doing,

```
if (scan.equals(" ")) {
    break;
}
```

which means you're comparing the Scanner object `scan` to a space. Try doing the following instead(you have to compare the scan.next() with a space):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseString<E> {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack();

    //while(scan.hasNext() && !stack.equals(" ")){
 //       while(!scan.nextLine().equals("")){
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String nextInput = scan.next();
        stack.push(nextInput );
        if (nextInput.equals(" ")) {
            break;
        }

    }

    System.out.print(stack.pop() + " ");


 }
}
```