# next() does't allow "white space" and nextLine() skips "sodaType" all together

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I have one problem. Neither of these work for my code.

When running this code with

> sodaType = keyboard.next();

userInput (called sodaType in code) only saves the first part of "Root Beer", outputting ("Root").

I googled the problem and

> sodaType = keyboard.nextLine();

Allows for "white space", but skips the userInput, outputting nothing, skipping the if statement.

I found different answers on this site

- [How do I make Java register a string input with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524243/how-do-i-make-java-register-a-string-input-with-spaces)
- [User Input not working with keyboard.nextLine() and String (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640718/user-input-not-working-with-keyboard-nextline-and-string-java)
- [Scanner doesn't see after space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509647/scanner-doesnt-see-after-space)

I am confused on why the nextLine() worked for them, and how I should continue.

```
while(true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a brand of soda. ");
        System.out.print("You can choose from Pepsi, Coke, Dr. Pepper, or Root Beer: ");
        sodaType = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("sodatype" + sodaType);
        if (sodaType.equalsIgnoreCase("pepsi") || sodaType.equalsIgnoreCase("coke") || 
                sodaType.equalsIgnoreCase("dr pepper") || sodaType.equalsIgnoreCase("dr. pepper") || 
                sodaType.equalsIgnoreCase("root beer")) 
        {
            System.out.println("you chose " +  sodaType);
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Please enter an avaiable brand of soda. ");

        }
    }
```

Comment: `outputting nothing, skipping the if statement` are you sure you pressed enter after the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because scanners work by separating the input into a sequence of 'tokens' and 'delimiters'. Out of the box, 'one or more whitespace characters' is the delimiter, thus, an input of:

```
Root Beer
Hello World
5
```

consists of 5 tokens: [`Root`, `Beer`, `Hello`, `World`, `5`]. What you want is that this forms 3 tokens: [`Root Beer`, `Hello World`, `5`].

Easy enough: Tell the scanner you intend for newlines to be the delimiter, and not just any whitespace:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
s.useDelimiter("\r?\n");
```

That's a regular expression that will match newlines regardless of OS.

Mixing `nextLine()` with any other next method in scanner leads to pain and suffering, so, don't do that. Forget nextLine exists.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score -1):

So When you write `.next()` this function reads `String` and read until it encounters a `white space`
So when you write this and give input as `root beer` it will read-only `root` cause after that `root` there's a `white space` which tells java to stop reading cause may be user wants to end the read.

```
sodaType = keyboard.next();
```

That's the reason why `.nextLint()` is introduce cause it will read the whole line as it is including `white spaces`.
So when you write and gave input like `root beer`

```
sodaType = keyboard.nextLine();
```

it will store it as `root beer`
and if you gave input as    `root beer`     it will store it as    `root beer`    
NOTE:  the exact number of white spaces.

Comment: The proper answer is useDelimiter; mixing nextLine and next causes big problems if the user ever enters spaces. I know 'use nextLine!' is common advice. It's common bad advice though.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thank you, I'll add this to my knowledge.